# How run less-plugin-glob in gulp like task?

Tags: npm, gulp, less

I want use https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob this plugin for multi importing less files.
When I run

> lessc --glob styles.less styles.css

from terminal - it's work fine, but I dont understand how I could run this command like gulp-task for every style build?

Comment: What do you mean "like gulp-task for every style build"? Do you want to use this plugin from your gulpfile? Are you talking about watching for changes? You'll have to be more specific if you want help.

Comment: Yes, I want use this plugin from my gulpfile. How I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`plugins` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less#using-plugins)  to pass the plugin to `gulp-less`. Example:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
    .pipe(less({
      plugins: [ require('less-plugin-glob') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});
```